# I failed a Triage Audit, but I would like to dispute it

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, triage, specific-audit

In reference to [How to efficiently explore third-party libraries in Haskell applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381663/how-to-efficiently-explore-third-party-libraries-in-haskell-applications) as an audit during triaging.

The question statement was/is:

> Therefore, I'm looking for recommendations how to best explore Haskell code. Is there a way to use ghci for that, even with a complex application stack? The debugger? Any other suggestions, that provide more insight than sprinkling trace statements all over my code?

I indicated it to be necessary for an "edit by author" to be edited into a fact-based question; it is in my assessment an abstract question that invites primarily subjective and opinion-based discussions as answers.

The audit indicated I failed, and I would like to dispute that on the same grounds - it is a discussion-orientated question that invites subjective and opinion-based answers.

Comment: not necessarily @gnat I am not inquiring as to the reasoning as to why audits can be flawed or reasonable. I am just disputing this specific audit.  Let it be a metric.

Comment: I think I'll accept this as being related and an answer for this posting actually.  In particular, the answers are relevant and instructive.

Comment: The question has since been closed, so it should no longer be being used as an audit.